# Error When Insert Current Time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cakephp

I want to insert current date and time when i add new record. But when i theres a problem. The date was correct but the time error. This is the code:

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s A',strtotime($value['Province']['created']));?>
```

When i add new data at 10/03/2017 18:40 PM, Then output will be 10/03/2017 11:41 Am. The time was wrong.
created is column name in table Province in database

Comment: What does `$value['Province']['created']` output? Can you give us a `var_dump`

Comment: what date/time you are getting and what is expected ? and what value have in `$value['Province']['created']` ?

Comment: make sure you can get timestamp or date in `$value['Province']['created']`

Comment: If it is really just the current date and time you want to insert, you can use `NOW()` in your query.

Comment: share the code from where you are inserting your date ?

Comment: it's cakephp problem or php problem ?

Comment: Name your CakePHP version... *Guess* it's 2.x

Comment: i using cakephp version CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not your actual version but just an info from a files copyright header. Please find the correct version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check this

In the config/core.php file of the app folder try the following with single quotes:

```
// Replace with your timezone ex. ('Asia/Kolkata') or
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, what was the problem and how this fixed ?

Comment: Now better , but I think @Felix not shared the code from where he is inserting. this code is for just displaying.

Comment: look his full question he says add new record @Niklesh

Comment: I think you are right , I thought here is missing word _But when i `display date` theres a problem_

Answer (score 1):

Use the TimeHelper for formatting dates in the view layer:

- Cake3 - https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html
- Cake2 - https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html

Give the fact that your post lacks information, I *assume* that your problem of the time difference is the timezone? Check the documentation as well on that, it shows how to change the timezone.